# Extbase: Modified object does not saved in the repository correctly

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am using TYPO3 7.6.10 and I build my first extension.

I want to add a property to my object in the createAction function of my controller.
But the modifications are nt saved.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * action create
 *
 * @param \Typo3\LpSurvey\Domain\Model\Sigil $newSigil
 * @param array $answers
 * @internal param Survey $newSurvey
 */
public function createAction(Sigil $newSigil, Array $answers)
{
    $newSurvey = $this->objectManager->get('Typo3\LpSurvey\Domain\Model\Survey');
    $this->userID = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'];

    //this modifications are saved
    foreach ($answers as $key => $answer) {
        $newSurveyItem = $this->objectManager->get('Typo3\LpSurvey\Domain\Model\SurveyItem');

        $newSurveyItem->setQuestionId($key);
        $newSurveyItem->setValue($answer);

        $newSurvey->addAnswer($newSurveyItem);
    }


    //BUT this modification is not saved
    $newSigil->setUserID($this->userID);

    $newSigil->setSurvey($newSurvey);

    $this->sigilRepository->add($newSigil);

    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

If I debug my object `$newSigil` the userID is set, but after adding to the repository the default value will be saved.

I dont understand why.
I also try to persist manually with following code, but no solution:

```
/**
 * @var \typo3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 * @inject
 */
protected $persistenceManager;

public function createAction(Sigil $newSigil, Array $answers)
{
    $newSurvey = $this->objectManager->get('Typo3\LpSurvey\Domain\Model\Survey');
    $this->userID = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'];


    foreach ($answers as $key => $answer) {
        $newSurveyItem = $this->objectManager->get('Typo3\LpSurvey\Domain\Model\SurveyItem');

        $newSurveyItem->setQuestionId($key);
        $newSurveyItem->setValue($answer);

        $newSurvey->addAnswer($newSurveyItem);
    }



    $newSigil->setUserID($this->userID);
    $newSigil->setSurvey($newSurvey);

    $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

    $this->sigilRepository->add($newSigil);

    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

I hope the question is understandable

Best regards Felix

Comment: Your code has the persistAll() before you add() the object. Try swapping that. If it still doesn't work theres something wrong with the object. Debug the $newSigil object instead of redirecting to listAction().

Comment: I have tried both before and behind, but no solution.
But we allready find a solution

Comment: I know it's an old question, but what was the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe UserID is not correct named? If your database field is called `user_id` your property for the domain should `userId`. Only if your database field is called `user_i_d` it should `userID`.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
But the error was not in the Controller rather in my domain model object. :)

Comment: thats why I wrote "property for the domain" ;)

Comment: Oh sorry I missed it xD